# Trigger .webtest/.loadtest from code

Tags: c#, .net, performance, visual-studio, webtest

I want to apply SpecFlow to a web test suite in Visual Studio. This will require a custom layer.

I want to know how to trigger webtests or loadtests from code (if that is possible). It feels like this should be supported, however I cant find any documentation.

Is this possible? Is there some API we can use to control the web test suite from an abstract layer? or do they have to be run from th Visual Studio UI or command line?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, run from Visual Studio or `mstest.exe` or a couple of other command line programs from Microsoft. It is not hard to write some code that will invoke another program such as `mstest.exe`.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute them with the MSTest.exe command line see here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2008/12/22/running-web-and-load-tests-from-the-command-line/

```
c:\>mstest /TestContainer:WebTest1.webtest
```

This will produce output similar to the following:

Loading WebTest1.webtest…

Starting execution…

Results               Top Level Tests
——-               —————
Passed                webtest1.webtest

1/1 test(s) Passed

Summary
——-
Test Run Completed.

Passed  1
 ———
  Total   1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.